# Different output from sprintf function in c++

Tags: c++, c, printf

The sprintf is not displaying the string message appropriately. The message to be displayed is
`Value out of range. Range is -2147483648 and 2147483647`. However it is printed as
`Value out of range. Range is -2147483648 and 0`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    __int64 tmpminVal = -2147483648;
    __int64 tmpmaxVal = 2147483647;

    std::string strTemp = "Value out of range. Range is %d and %i ";
    char buffer[100];
    int n = sprintf (buffer, strTemp.c_str(), tmpminVal,tmpmaxVal);
    strTemp = buffer;
    std::cout << strTemp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please provide the reason why it is does so.

Comment: `%d` and `%i` are for `int` but you provide `__int64`. This causes undefined behaviour. You will need to find out what your platform's specifier is for `__int64`.  (If you use `long long` instead then `%lld` is the specifier).

Comment: `%d` and `%i` expect an `int`, not an `__int64`. What you see is probably the effect of `tmpminVal` being split into two chunks of 32 bits each.

Comment: The correct format specifier for `__int64` is [`%I64d`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx).

Comment: thanks all. I defined the variables as long int and used the format specifier as %ld. and it is working fine.

Comment: @user657267, %I64d is not present in Linux. I wanted a general solution which works in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @suma `%I64d is not present in Linux` neither is `__int64`.

Comment: %I64d is not a standar specifier, as also isn't __int64, and also isn't long long (long long is a nonportable extension of some revision of ansi-c)  You'll have to work on it if you want it to be portable.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? If so, you should accept the most valuable answer.

Answer (score 2):

[You can find printf parameters](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

As you see `%d` is signed integer, integer in this case means 32-bit. Go further to *specifiers table* and you will see, that to print 64-bit (`long long`) you need to use specifier `ll`, so you need `%lld`, not `%d`.

---

Your result (-2147483648 and 0) is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

---

Also as I see from comments, you want cross platform solution, so you should use `long long` instead of `__int64`, as this one is Windows type.

Answer (score 1):

You passing two `long long`'s to a function which expects two `int`s. Either change `%d` and `%i` to `%ll` or change `__int64` to `int`.

Comment: Changing the format directive from `"%d"` to `"%ll"` is certainly wrong.  Suspect you meant `"%lld"`.  Even `"%lld"` is not a great solution. `"%lld"` is for `long long`.  `long long` may not be the same size as `__int64`.  MS calls for `"I64d"`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 1):

So, as the other answers also say, you're invoking undefined behavior by passing a `int64` to a format string expecting an `int`

Instead, you should use `stdint.h` and `inttypes.h`. On Linux, these will be included, and under Windows, you can include this project to use them: https://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/

An example use would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int64_t tmpminVal = -2147483648;
    int64_t tmpmaxVal = 2147483647;

    std::string strTemp = "Value out of range. Range is %" PRId64 " and % " PRIi64 " ";
    char buffer[100];
    int n = sprintf (buffer, strTemp.c_str(), tmpminVal,tmpmaxVal);
    strTemp = buffer;
    std::cout << strTemp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can also find some documentation about these header files at cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer